# How to add id to Ruby on Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to have a # in my route so it can scroll down to that id but the # is the ruby comment so when I try to add it it just comments it out. is there a way to change this?

My routes file

```
get '#about_me', to: 'pages#home'
```

Here is where im trying to add the # before `#about_me_path` in my application controller

```
def nav_items
[
  {
    url: root_path,
    title: 'Home'
  },
  {
   url: about_me_path,
   title: 'About Me'
  },
  {
    url: contact_path,
    title: 'Contact'
  },
  {
    url: blogs_path,
    title: 'Blog'
  },
  {
    url: portfolios_path,
    title: 'Portfolio'
  },
  {
    url: tech_news_path,
    title: 'Tech Tweets'
  }

]
```

end

Comment: Can you add more detail about your second section of code?  Which file is this in? A view, controller? Can you show the whole method that you are trying to execute?

Comment: You can use the `anchor` option to the path helper: `tech_news_path(anchor: 'about_me')`.

Comment: I turned it into a string and then I just changed the id to match what was created and that worked just fine. Thanks @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 0):

I tried what @MrYoshiji said and put #about_me_path into a string which changed my application controller to look like this

```
def nav_items
[
  {
    url: root_path,
    title: 'Home'
  },
  {
   url: '#about_me_path',
   title: 'About Me'
  },
  {
    url: contact_path,
    title: 'Contact'
  },
  {
    url: blogs_path,
    title: 'Blog'
  },
  {
    url: portfolios_path,
    title: 'Portfolio'
  },
  {
    url: tech_news_path,
    title: 'Tech Tweets'
  }

]
end
```

That fixed my problem

Comment: Although putting it in a string worked, it didn't work from other sections of the site. However, using the anchor option and switching the about_me_path to root path it worked just fine from all sections.